# How to run PowerShell script file without SDK?

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell

I have a PowerShell script (ps file) which I'd like to run from a C# WPF app on the clients' machine. Most of the examples I found uses the PowerShell SDK, but I can not install that on the client computers.

If I try to run my script simply with Process.Start like this:

```
Process.Start("Powershell.exe", "myscript.ps");
```

I get the following error in the command window:

```
File myscript.ps cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ myscript.ps
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

I looked at the link but I can not set the ExecutionPolicy on the machines of the clients.

Is there any other way to run a PS script from a C# client app without using the SDK or setting the ExecutionPolicy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, I don't know C#, but there's a command line option for powershell.exe that will help you I'm pretty sure.

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

Comment: I found the solution just this moment, this is the whole C# code that worked for me: `Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"/c powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted myscript.ps1");`. So Unrestricted worked for me, I haven't tried Bypass. Thanks!

Comment: Either Unrestricted or Bypass should work. I am not sure what the difference is.

Comment: `Bypass` == no restrictions, no warnings; `Unrestricted` == no restrictions, but a warning with confirmation prompt is shown for unsigned scripts downloaded from the web.