# Run a Powershell script inside of a C# project

Tags: c#, powershell

So I want to run a powershell script inside of a c# project. The powershell file would be located in a folder inside the project. I am just not sure how to reference that file from c# to run it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run PowerShell script file without SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790362/how-to-run-powershell-script-file-without-sdk)

Answer (score 2):

Please do a google search before you ask here

https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/archive/blogs/kebab/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c

https://duanenewman.net/blog/post/running-powershell-scripts-from-csharp/

```
var ps1File = @"C:\my script folder\script.ps1";
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = "powershell.exe",
        Arguments = $"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -file \"{ps1File}\"",
        UseShellExecute = false
    };
    Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: I realize how to run a script that is located outside of the project. To clarify I meant that the script is located inside the project solution. For example: "Scripts\script.ps1"

Comment: Why don't you read the file as stream, save it into TMP folder and then launch it using this solution?